# Unknown command 'zremrangebyrank'

Tags: redis

On my local machine, redis works perfectly when I command

```
zremrangebyrank city 0 -1
```

But when I try to do it on the dev server i receive:

Unknown command 'zremrangebyrank'

Any idea why?

Comment: http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank

Comment: What version of redis do you have there? This command is only for 2.0+

Comment: what's the command to learn the version?

Comment: http://redis.io/commands/info

Comment: redis_version:1.2.6.
Damn. I need to update redis. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

This command is only for redis v2.0.0+

It is not supported in older versions (you have 1.2.6).